# Django Annotate- Grouping along multiple .annotate() functions

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following manager, which is working correctly.

```
def by_customer_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):

    qs = self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "customer__name"
    ).annotate(
        grand_total_cogs=Sum('total_cogs'),
        total_sales=Sum('value'),
        total_profit=Sum('profit'),
        total_kgs=Sum('qty_applied'),
        current_balance=Sum('sale__receiptallocation__qty_applied')
    ).order_by('-total_kgs')
```

Results are [properly grouped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#values) by customer name by using `.values("customer__name")`

However, what I'd like to do is this:

```
def by_customer_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):

    qs = self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "customer__name"
    ).annotate(
        grand_total_cogs=Sum('total_cogs'),
        total_sales=Sum('value'),
        total_profit=Sum('profit'),
        total_kgs=Sum('qty_applied'),
        current_balance=Sum('sale__receiptallocation__qty_applied')
    ).annotate(
         margin=Case(
             When(total_sales=0, then=0),
             default=(F('profit')) / (F('value'))*100
         )
     ).order_by('-total_kgs')
```

I am using the annotated values to calculate another value whose denominator may be zero (hence the use of `Case(When)`). When I add this portion, the `.values("customer__name")` function loses it's effect, and each individual item is shown.

I've tried moving the `.values("customer__name")` portion to the end (with added explicit references to each field name), but the issue remains.

Is this the intended behavior? Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that the second `annotate()` must be placed at the very end of the expression. The proper order of these in my example should be as follows:

`self.model.objects.filter().values().annotate().order_by().annotate()`

Here is the result:

```
def by_customer_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):

    qs = self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "customer__name"
    ).annotate(
        grand_total_cogs=Sum('total_cogs'),
        total_sales=Sum('value'),
        total_profit=Sum('profit'),
        total_kgs=Sum('qty_applied'),
        current_balance=Sum('sale__receiptallocation__qty_applied'),
    ).order_by(
        '-total_kgs'
    ).annotate(
        final_margin=Case(
            When(total_sales=0, then=0),
            default=(Sum(F('profit')) / Sum(F('value')))*100
        )
    )

    return qs
```